# Performance profiling in Pig Scripts

Tags: apache-pig

Some of my pig scripts take a long time to execute as the data on which they run map reduce jobs is huge. So, I was just thinking of ways to speed up the script . Can somebody suggest any ideas and put their thoughts .
There are a lot of GROUP BY fields involved while I group data based on a combination of two or three fields.

One idea that I can think of is having one extra field while doing GROUP BY

```
Data = GROUP BY (int) (RANDOM()*100) as reducers, field1, field2 etc
```

Will it help as it will involve more number of reducers by introducing one extra field in GROUP BY. I know the output part file sizes will become lesser , but will it overall speedify the running time of pig scripts.

Comment: And if it does speedify the whole process what should be the number of reducers that I should ideally set or tuning it involves experimentation.

Comment: It's not direct solution to your problem, but you can use [explain operator](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/test.html#explain) to see how your pig script will be translated to execution plan.